# keyup function with form submit

Tags: jquery, keyevent

I have a function where I have a keyup on my textbox. Once I hit the "S" key and the form will submit. But the problem is, whenever I press the "S" key, it adds to the textbox and it is included in the textbox value and it is submitted. How can I avoid it when pressing "S", it should not be included in the textbox. Just do the submit without S value in textbox.

As you can see here in my image, there's a "S" on the last value. My target is to avoid that whenever I'm submitting my form using "S" key.

[image]

Thank you

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btnsub').keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which === 83)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#insertEntryy').click();
            console.log('1');
        
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="blabla">
<input type="text" class="btnsub">

<button id="insertEntryy" type="button">
asd
</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `keydown` handler which prevents 's' from being added:

```
$('.btnsub').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 83)
    {
        event.preventDefault();  
    }
});
```

So your whole script becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btnsub').keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which === 83)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            $('#insertEntryy').click();
            console.log('1');
        
        }
    });

    // New handler:
    $('.btnsub').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.which === 83)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect. This is what i needed. I'll study about this. Thank you. Appreciated

Comment: Hi, just a follow-up question, what if the user wants to type an "S" in the textbox? In my current function, when the user types "S" it automatically submits. May I ask you to suggest how I should approach that kind of scenario? Ty

Comment: @UlquiorraSchiffer Change `if (event.which === 83)` to `if (String.fromCharCode(event.which).toUpperCase() == 'S')`.

Answer (score 1):

If your input accepts only numbers, use Regex: `/[a-zA-Z]/g` and `.replace()` so you filter out letters. If you want everything *but 's'* Regex: `/[sS]/g` (Replacement filter for all letters is commented).

BTW, the form can't submit unless the `<button>` has `type="submit"` or no `type` at all (you probably already know that, but it needed to be said for future readers).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btnsub').on('keyup', function(e) {
      const rgx = new RegExp(/[sS]/, 'g');
      // const rgx = new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z]/, 'g')
      if (rgx.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(rgx,'');
      }
      if (e.key === 's') {
        $('#insertEntryy').click();
        console.log('clicked');
      }
      console.log(this.value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="blabla">
<input type="text" class="btnsub">
<button id="insertEntryy" type='button'>
asd
</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This works with my other function. I'll use this one for others but not for this function. Thank you appreciated

Comment: Sorry, updated. Changed `$('input')` to `$(.btnsub')`

Comment: Hi, just a follow-up question, what if the user wants to type an "S" in the textbox? In my current function, when the user types "S" it automatically submits. May I ask you to suggest how I should approach that kind of scenario? Ty

Comment: I already updated it, it filters "s" and "S" with regex `/[sS]/`. Give it a try.